# ¿Se debe dejar un espacio entre los puntos suspensivos y el texto cuando aquellos preceden a este?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

No sé por qué, pero yo siempre he escrito los puntos suspensivos pegados al texto, incluso si la parte omitida va delante de este:

> ...y así es como se usan los *streams* en Java.

Supongo que esto lo hago debido a que cuando van al final de frase, se deben escribir pegados al texto, pero no estoy seguro de cuál es la norma en el caso de que deban preceder al texto. Sé que en el caso de una cita textual, si se ha omitido parte del texto citado, deben ir separados, con el uso de corchetes opcional:

> *"[...] a hablar de mi libro. ¿Qué estríns ni qué niño muerto?"*
>
> Francistack Umbralflow.

Sin embargo, ¿cuál es la norma cuando los puntos suspensivos están reflejando que el hablante ha reanudado el diálogo después de una pausa dubitativa? ¿Y cuando se quiere reflejar que sólo se ha pronunciado la parte final de una palabra?

¿Serían válidos los siguientes ejemplos?

> —No me ha quedado claro cómo se usan los... —Julia se quedó pensando un momento, no recordaba la palabra— ...*strings* en Java.
>   —...ava... ...ava... ...ava... —respondió el eco del aula vacía.

¿Hay algún otro caso en el que se puedan usar puntos suspensivos pegados a la palabra que sigue? ¿O definitivamente esa norma me la he inventado yo?

Answer (score 3):

La *Ortografía de la lengua española (2010)* [nos da la pauta](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UeXTCzTWiYzjhaDZ):

[image]

También podemos consultar la página de [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Puntos_suspensivos) que también trata el tema:

> En los textos impresos aparecen siempre pegados a la palabra o el
>   signo que los precede, y separados por un espacio de la palabra o el
>   signo que los sigue (lo que incluye los puntos suspensivos que marcan
>   un texto omitido en una cita); pero si lo que sigue a los puntos
>   suspensivos es otro signo de puntuación, no se deja espacio entre
>   ambos.
>
> ```
>     ... fue la aglutinación de los pueblos eslavos de la monarquía austrohúngara. 
>     En la Grecia peninsular (Tirinto, Vafio...) se situan lo centros de este estilo.
> ```

Siguiendo estas normas el ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

> —No me ha quedado claro cómo se usan los...—Julia se quedó pensando 
>   un momento, no recordaba la palabra—... strings en Java. —... ava...
>   ava... ava...—respondió el eco del aula vacía.

La única cosa que no me queda muy clara es qué se hace cuando hay dos puntos suspensivos seguidos, según la norma deberían ir pegados pero eso sería bastante extraño y el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=c5GublcDAD6kWvCUUy) dice: *«Signo de puntuación formado por tres puntos consecutivos (...) —y solo tres—»*. Yo entiendo que escribir seis puntos seguidos es poco menos que una aberración.

Según mi propio criterio creo que la mejor opción es poner solo un grupo de puntos suspensivos cada vez.

Comment: @Charlie ¿De dónde has sacado el link?

Comment: Cuando tengas los resultados de la búsqueda en la _Gramática_ u _Ortografía_ ([ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84d4p.png)) haz clic con el botón derecho sobre el icono de la cámara de la fila correspondiente al resultado deseado, y copia la dirección del enlace. :-)

Comment: ¿Podrías proponer entonces cómo quedaría el último ejemplo expuesto en la pregunta siguiendo la pauta general?